# Tridion Docs - Applying Custom Metadata Fields on a Particular Topic Type

Tags: cme, configuration, tridion-docs

I want to add custom metadata fields to a specific Topic Type "Task".

I have added the custom metadata fields as described [here](https://www.contentbloom.com/blog/how-to-connect-tridion-dx-unified-taxonomies-in-a-meaningful-way/). Since I don't want the metadata fields on other object types than Topics, I just added `FormGroup` of my custom fields to "Module.GeneralTabPage" `FormTab` in MetadataConfig.xml.(As highlighted in the image below)

[image]

This works fine and the custom metadata fields are shown on the Topics but my requirement is to show the fields only on the "Task" topic type. To achieve this I tried adding many conditions on the From Group tag (as well as on the fields tags) but none of the below condition works:

ishcondition="FMODULETYPE='VMODULETYPETASK'"

ishcondition="DMODULETYPE='VMODULETYPETASK'"

ishcondition="FMODULETYPE='Task'"

ishcondition="DMODULETYPE='Task'"

ishcondition="ModuleType='VMODULETYPETASK'"

ishcondition="ModuleType='Task'"

I also referred to the [SDL Documentation about ish conditions](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-411D5ED5-B11C-4224-84C6-C8DBBEC45339) in MetadataConfig.xml and it looks like the above is not possible to achieve by updating the MetadataConfig.xml as the variables in the ish conditions might not be available to metadataConfig.xml.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to apply metadata only to a particular Topic Type?

   2. If yes, Is it possible by updating the metadataConfig.xml or there?

      3. If yes, what would be the correct ish condition for it?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, as of now in tridion docs metadata will be available for all types of topic, you can not define metadata exclusively for one topic type.

Comment: Thanks @NeeteshNarvaria. Is there a documentation or some other reference confirming it?